# How to undo the "toString()" function

Tags: javascript

JavaScript's `toString` function has 1 parameter: the base. If I use `(2)`, then the output string will be in binary, `(16)` -> hex, `(8)` -> octal. These aren't the only bases it supports; it supports up to base 36.

```js
1234567890n.toString(36)
```

The result of that expression is:

```
kf12oi
```

Since this is a pure unary function that doesn't result in data lost, I was guessing there is a way to undo it too, right?

I'm trying not to use the number prefixes such as `0b`, `0x`, or `0o`, since they don't cover everything.

If the answer isn't cross compatible, it's still acceptable.

## Update

Sorry, I forgot to mention, the input is actually a `BigInt` and is considered to be `Infinity` when using `parseInt()`.

Comment: `parseInt("kf12oi", 36);` will give you the desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just parse the number back with:

```
parseInt('kf12oi', 36); // 1234567890
```

---

If the number can't fit in the Number type. You should manually convert the number:

```js
parseBigInt = (value = '0', base = 10) => [].reduce.call(value,
  (acc, x) => acc * BigInt(base) + BigInt(parseInt(x, base)), 0n);

valB10 = '1' + [...new Array(600)].map(x => Math.random() * 10 | 0).join('');
console.log('%s', BigInt(valB10));

valB36 = BigInt(valB10).toString(36);
console.log(valB36);

parsed = parseBigInt(valB36, 36);
console.log('%s', parsed);

console.log(BigInt(valB10) === parsed);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm unable to accept any answers for 10 minutes. But thank you both, nonetheless.

Comment: Updated question.

Comment: Didn't understand your update. `BigInt(parseInt(1234567890n.toString(36), 36))` works for me.

Comment: I didn't write the whole number on purpose. It's well over 600 digits long

Comment: Give us a long enough number to try it.

Comment: 718281828459045235360287471352662497757247093699959574966967627724076630353547594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630738132328627943490763233829880753195251019011573834187930702154089149934884167509244761460668082264800168477411853742345442437107539077744992069551702761838606261331384583000752044933826560297606737113200709328709127443747047230696977209310141692836819025515108657463772111252389784425056953696770785449969967946864454905987931636889230098793127736178215424999229576351482208269895193668033182528869398496465105820939239829488793320362509443117

Comment: Okay, I made a small javascript app to test out this case. I'm using an own number, which is apparently big enough. https://jsfiddle.net/opjd7kre/2/

Comment: I've updated with a simple conversion method... I can't afford spend more time now, but later I'll try to make a faster version using recursion or something like that.

Comment: So the final answer would be @WashingtonGuedes conversion method, which consists of that f function. Someone could extract the number system out of it. I've double checked, it works. I didn't try it for the whole BigInt range though.

Comment: I've being thinking in background while working... it just seems wrong to me, there should be better compression methods instead of using `[0-9a-z]` range of 36 characters.

Comment: Who said, he wanna use it for compression?

Comment: My mind can't go further in imagination :/ ... @Red What's the usecase to the numbers in base 36?

Answer (score 1):

use `parseInt` to convert any radical number to the decimal

```js
let num = 23;

let inBinary = num.toString(2);

console.log(inBinary);

let backtoDecimal = parseInt(inBinary, 2)

console.log(backtoDecimal)
```